# How to request get value?

Tags: php

How can i echo PHP Get request with []?
example: `value=ok&params[account]=123456`
There is no problem with:

```
echo $value = $_GET["value"];
```

Not working with:

```
echo $account = $_GET["params[account]"];
```

Comment: It's `$_GET["params"]["account"]`.

Comment: Hi @aronsimt, if you have the solution via message, can you close the question? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo $account = $_GET["params"]["account"];
```